# How do I normalize a subset of a dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

I have a set of 500 values out of which 20 are relevant to my project and will be used to train for ML.
Should I take the 20 values and then normalize them or normalize all 500 and then extract the subset?
What factors influence this decision?

Comment: Should this have a self-study tag? What type of machine learning? Are the 20 a random selection or are the 20 relevant because they are the only ones with a certain characteristic of interest (e.g. the only ones in Delaware)?

Comment: 20 samples might be two small in order to estimate the distribution. Since you assume that this distribution exists (and normal?) and that all the 500 values are from the same distribution,  it is better to use all the values. Please note that in case that you assume normal distribution and you are wrong, you might make your data less useful. It is a good habit to test the distribution before normalization.

Comment: This question seems clear enough to me. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: @DanLevin, why not turn that into an official answer?

Comment: I thought it is too small remark to be an answer. I turned it into an answer now.

Comment: The major factor to influence the decision is a more precise description of what exactly you want to do. ML what? There are thousands of methods, and how they are affected by normalisation depends on the method.

Answer (score 0):

20 samples might be two small in order to estimate the distribution. Since you assume that this distribution exists (and normal?) and that all the 500 values are from the same distribution, it is better to use all the values. Please note that in case that you assume normal distribution and you are wrong, you might make your data less useful. It is a good habit to test the distribution before normalization.